# Erro ao usar comando sql Insert(SQL Server), via ASP clássico

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp

Boa noite, estou com um problema ao executar um comando sql através de uma aplicação em ASP.

O Comando é este:

```
strSql =    " INSERT INTO movimento_tef_nsu (           "&_
            "   identificador                           "&_
            "   ,nsu_sitef                              "&_
            "   ,valor                                  "&_
            "   ,ordem_cartao                           "&_
            "   ,data_hora                              "&_
            "   ,texto_comprovante                      "&_
            "   )                                       "&_
            " VALUES (                                  "&_
            "   '" & objJSON.data("identificador") & "' "&_
            "   ," & this.item("nsu")                   &_
            "   ," & this.item("valor")                 &_
            "   ," & this.item("ordem_cartao")          &_
            "   ,'" & this.item("data_hora") & "' "     &_           
            "   ,LEFT('" & this.item("texto_comprovante") & "', 255) "&_
            "   )                                       "
```

Já verifiquei que os valores(que estão vindo via JSON), estão corretos, pois gravo em um Log antes de executar o comando.

O erro que ocorre é o seguinte:

> "An unspecified error occurred! Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server, error '80040e14'. Syntax error or access violation"

Verifiquei também que os valores estão vindo de acordo com o tipo e tamanho dos campos no banco de dados, tanto é que se eu pegar a query que está no log e rodar no sql management, funciona normalmente.

Alguém tem uma sugestão do que pode ser este erro?

Comment: Por acaso tem alguma aspa simples no `texto_comprovante`? Você pode postar a string SQL final gerada pelo ASP?

Comment: não deveria fechar aspas depois dos "& this.item("nsu")... ?

Comment: Tente obter a SQL gerada e tente rodar diretamente no Banco. Mas eu olharia este ", 255" ele parece "solto"

Comment: @Dante, não àquela linha está correta. Se o OP consegue rodar essa query no SMS então o problema é na montagem da "string" ou na conexão. Verifique se vc está conectado à base correta. Tente, ao invés de "buildar" a string, um query de insert/update simples

Comment: Galera, segui o que @jean disse e verifiquei que o objeto connection não estava setado na base correta(de alguma forma, perdeu a configuração no meio do caminho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está aqui

```
",LEFT('" & this.item("texto_comprovante") & "', 255) "
```

a virgula do left faz com que o mySQL entenda que existe mais um parâmetro, para resolver, use a função antes de chamar a query, guarde em uma variável e a use no INSERT.

---

```
 textoComprovante = LEFT('" & this.item("texto_comprovante") & "', 255)

strSql = " INSERT INTO movimento_tef_nsu 
   (identificador, nsu_sitef, valor, ordem_cartao,data_hora, texto_comprovante) 
    VALUES
    ('" & objJSON.data("identificador") & "', " & this.item("nsu") & ", " & this.item("valor")
    &", " & this.item("ordem_cartao") &", '" & this.item("data_hora") & "', '" & textoComprovante & "'")
```

---

Comment: A base dele é MS-SQL e não MySQL. Vlw Flw